# Why was this suggested edit submitted by an anonymous user rejected?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

[This edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/200175) was rejected by 2 users and approved by one, I was going to approve it but got the message that it had already been rejected. It sounded like the OP submitted the edit and it didn't change the post in any dramatic way.

If we got the possibility to submit edits without logging in why is an edit like this rejected? To me that defeats the purpose of having anonymous edits.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because it was seen as somebody editing a post that wasn't theirs. In this case it's not neccessarily obvious that the original poster didn't fully register and so probably didn't get the same session when they came back.

I'll edit it back in.

---

To the comments: The pros and cons of the unregistered editing and accounts system is really quite irrelevant here. It is what it is.

I considered the edit to be probably from the OP. I made that assumption on the basis that there's nothing harmful in the edit (it's not spam) and it's a continuation of the question, adding more information, and that it doesn't conflict with the existing question (unlikely to be a hijack of some sort).

Oh and that doing that "maliciously" accomplishes nothing. And even if they did, the OP could roll it back, flag, comment, etc to let us know that something untoward had happened.

I'd expect people to treat these sorts of edits with *scrutiny* but not absolute and automatic rejection.

Comment: But Oli, how OP will know (if he ever gets his cookie back) about answers? How will he accept the one that helped him? How folks can actually help if OP has no means to answer comments? Who knows that it's actually OP and not somebody hi-hacking?

Comment: @Braiam Which is why we need required registration. Just because he OP doesn't have access to his account anymore is no reason to not help him. It's one of the glitches in the system.

Comment: @Braiam Edited.

Answer (score 0):

> It sounded like the OP

Who knows?

Comment: But if it wasn't the OP then we could have rollbacked the edit, and if it was the OP then he/she would have been happy. So what do we have to loose?

Comment: @Alvar and if OP lost forever it's cookie and can log in again?

Comment: cookie? what are you talking about? Don't you mean log-in information? What if the OP got two computers, or two browsers. Then he needs way more than one cookie....

Comment: @Alvar no, he needs to register himself.