# Edit proposed by anonymous user ?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, anonymous-users

[This edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/628489) is in my review queue.

Note that it's "proposed by an anonymous user" - what does this mean?

I've already read [this suggested dupe](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7889/why-was-this-suggested-edit-submitted-by-an-anonymous-user-rejected), and it didn't help me.

Comment: You need to determine if " Adding the call for aptitude as well" is useful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Proposed by an anonymous user" means the edit was suggested by someone who wasn't signed into an Ask Ubuntu account. It's possible to contribute to Stack Exchange sites without having an account, and it's fairly common to see edits proposed anonymously (I see it at least once a week).

Sometimes, the proposed edit is actually the original post author trying to change their own post. If I can tell this is the case, then I will follow the link to the post and leave a comment reminding the user to log in to edit their post.

In general though, I don't think you need to treat these suggested edits any differently from others you review - I think you should determine whether or not the edit has value in your opinion, and review it accordingly.